# How can I configure a mail server to support wildcard addresses and catch them with a server script?

Tags: postfix, email-server, mx-record, wildcard

Hello I'd like to know if it's possible to configure a mail server to support wildcard addresses like  %@example.com or *@example.com  and send those incoming emails not in a mailbox (cause they would be 'virtual' email addresses) but catch them in a server script (run a sh or php)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Basically, you need to edit three config files:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual**

```
@example.com example
```

**/etc/aliases**

```
example: "|/path/to/the/script"
```

For more information, have a look at [the Postfix Virtual Domain Hosting Howto](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html)